# Trouble fully abstracting data access method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, abstract-class

I'm abstracting my data access layer in to a centralised generic abstract class so that my other type specific classes can just call the generic methods without defining implementation.

```
public abstract class _DALMethods<T>
{
    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        List<T> ents = new List<T>();

        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            ents = db.tblEmployees.ToList();
        }

        return ents;
    }

    public virtual void Add(T obj)
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            db.tblEmployees.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is how to "generic-ise" the very specific call to the employee table `DbSet` list, especially when it requires the instantiation of the EF entities.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    ents = db.tblEmployees.ToList();
}
```

**EDIT:** I added another method to the abstract class that I will be using. How would I do the same for this?

Comment: Per your update it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking a couple of questions. Firstly, if you want the Entities constructor part to be generic, you'll have to add a generic parameter to you class, maybe like this:

```
public abstract class _DALMethods<TEntities, T> where TEntities : DbContext, new() where T: class
```

Then you can call:

```
using (var db = new TEntities())
```

Secondly, to get the entities generically you can use

```
db.Set<T>().ToList();
```

Which will return all entities from the DbSet

For your add method, something like this should help:

Replace

```
db.tblEmployees.Add(obj);
```

with

```
db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Comment: I get a lot of errors when I implement this. `TEntities must be convertible to IDisposable` and `Cannot create an instance of TEntities because it does not have the new() constraint`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the constraints to the class

Comment: That's great. What does `TModel` refer to though?

Comment: TModel is just a generic reference to the model, so when you instantiate your _DALMethods class, you would have to call new _DALMethods<Entities, tblEmployees> - or something to that effect

Comment: Ok I see thanks. I added another method to the class, how would this play out for adding an entity since there is no concern for returned values?

Comment: See updated answer - note that I added an extra constraint to the class declaration

Comment: Thanks that's great. I keep getting `T must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter TEntity` have I missed something?

Comment: Note that I added an additional constraint to the class declaration (i.e. where T: class)

Comment: We're getting closer :) just getting a warning now that `TModel` as a type parameter is not defined. Should it be included with `T` and `TEntities`?

Comment: Sorry - TModel was meant to be TEntities!!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this might work:

```
List<T> ents = new List<T>();

using (var db = new Entities())
{
    //ents = db.Set<T>().ToList(T);
    // correction due to Kyle and Lee below
    ents = db.Set<T>().ToList<T>();
}

return ents;
```

(I'm using EF 6). The `Set<T>` returns a `DbSet<T>`.

Cheers -

Comment: `T` can't be used as an argument to ToList.  Also the first assignment to ents is unnecessary (ents is either overwritten or an exception is thrown and execution never makes it to the return statement anyway).

Comment: @Kyle is right I get errors when attempting this: `T is a type and is used as a variable` and `Type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter`

Comment: Apologies: that should have been ToList<T>();

Comment: That solved some of the errors thanks, but I'm still getting the `T Must be a reference type..` error

Comment: Change the class declaration to - public abstract class _DALMethods<T> where T : class

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're looking for the [`DbContext.Set<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method:

```
public virtual List<T> GetAll()
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        return db.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

then:

```
var dal = new _DALMethods<Employee>();
var employees = dal.GetAll(); // returns a List<Employee>
```